# Any snowflake-jdbc query throws NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.size()" because "this.currentConverters" is null

Tags: jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to execute a simple JDBC query against a Snowflake database, just to test the connectivity.

In my pom,

```xml
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.snowflake/snowflake-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.snowflake</groupId>
        <artifactId>snowflake-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.15.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I can successfully create a connection. My credentials are accepted as valid. However, even the simplest of queries results in an NPE thrown from within the `net.snowflake.client` package.

```kotlin
val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, connectionProperties)

connection.prepareStatement("select 1")
          .executeQuery()
          .getInt(1)
```

Executing this results in the following error:

> ```java
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.size()" because "this.currentConverters" is null
>   at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.ArrowResultChunk$ArrowChunkIterator.getCurrentConverter(ArrowResultChunk.java:462)
>   at net.snowflake.client.core.SFArrowResultSet.getInt(SFArrowResultSet.java:408)
>   at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeResultSetV1.getInt(SnowflakeResultSetV1.java:192)
> ```

I'm dumbfounded that my "hello world" program resulted in an internal error in the library.

Surely there must be a way to solve this? Am I missing some other dependency, maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, I forgot to call `next` before using the result set.

I took a look at the `ArrowResultChunk` code, and it turns out that `currentConverters` is not initialized until `ResultSet::next` is called.

So, here is a working version of the above code (with auto closing resources too)

```kotlin
connection.prepareStatement("select 1").use { ps ->
    ps.executeQuery().use { rs ->
        rs.next()
        rs.getInt(1)
    }
}
```